# Hover using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, hover

Having a bit of problem debugging my jQuery code...

In order to allow hover effects on block elements (such as `div`) in IE, I want to use jQuery to do the trick instead of css. My jQuery code looks something like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("div.foo").mouseover(function(){
            $("div.foo h3").addClass("hover");
        }).mouseout(function(){
            $("div.foo h3").removeClass("hover");
    });
});
```

This works as my header switch between `h3` and `h3.hover`, **BUT** if I try to:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("div.bar").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).addClass("hover");
        }).mouseout(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
    });
});
```

This won't work in **all versions of IE**. Does it mean IE has trouble detecting multiple classes on 1 element (which is `div.bar.hover`)? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

After examined the code, I realised the problem lies in a conflict with javascript `curvycorners-2.0.4` (which is another IE hack) that were also applied to this element.

Comment: div is not a non-block element, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use toggleClass instead:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("div.bar").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("hover");
        }).mouseout(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    });
});
```

It will add class if not there, and remove if already applied.

And correct: `div.bar.hover` is not valid CSS selector for IE6. instead do something like that: `#myPanel div.hover`.

Answer (score 2):

Even shorter:

```
$('div.bar').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

True, IE6 cant handle multiple classes in CSS, f.ex:

```
div.one.two{color:red}
```

wont work for `<div class="one two">red</div>`

**Update:**
It might be a bubbling issue as well, try using the .hover helper http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover to prevent that.

Comment: I tested on all versions, not just IE6.

Answer (score 1):

The sample provided by you works flawless in IE6 (can't check IE7/8). Check here

http://jsbin.com/uyopi