# Have multiple TD and onmouseover and onmouseout change bg color

Tags: jquery, hover

```
<table border=0 cellPadding=5 cellSpacing=0 width=100%>
            <tr>
                <td colSpan=5 align=center><a href="index.html" title="Home"><img src="theImages/logoAlone.png" /></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colSpan=5 height=15></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=18% class=fdBBorder id=type1><A href="findDoctors.html">Find A Doctor</a></td>
                <td width=18% class=fdBBorder id=type2><A href="patSvc.html">Patient Services</a></td>
                <td width=18% class=fdBBorder id=type3><A href="mapNDir.html">Maps & Directions</a></td>
                <td width=18% class=fdBBorder id=type4><A href="trainProgs.html">Training Programs</a></td>
                <td width=18% class=fdBBorder id=type5><A href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align=left valign=top id=type11>
                    <div class=mainP><img src="theImages/greenArrow.png" align=absmiddle /> <A href="findDoctors.html">Doctor's List</a></div>
                    <div class=mainP><img src="theImages/greenArrow.png" align=absmiddle /> <A href="findDoctors.html">Staff Highlight</a></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align=left valign=top id=type22>
                    <div class=mainP><img src="theImages/greenArrow.png" align=absmiddle /> <A href="findDoctors.html">Doctor's List</a></div>
                    <div class=mainP><img src="theImages/greenArrow.png" align=absmiddle /> <A href="findDoctors.html">Staff Highlight</a></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

My question is if i hover over Find a Doctor, i want that TD to change bgColor and also the bgColor for TD id type22, pretty much change multiple TD background color when you put your mouseover on type1?
How do i create a jquery for that?
I have this but this changed the color onload:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#type1").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#type11").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

But i want this to be on hover.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775068/hover-using-jquery). Your solution will be like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#type1").mouseover(function(){
      $("#type1").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#type22").css("background-color", "red");
   }).mouseout(function(){
      $("#type1").css("background-color", "");
      $("#type22").css("background-color", "");
    });
});​
```

Check it out this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MqUyx/)

**UPDATED**
Since you asked me how to two different id to do same mouseover functions. You will need it to be an external function. Something like:

```
  $("#type1").mouseover(function(){highlight()});
  $("#type22").mouseover(function(){highlight()});
  function highlight() {
      $("#type1").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#type22").css("background-color", "red");
  }
```

See [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/u6jrW/)

Comment: if i want to put two can i just say: $("#type1 #type22").mouseover(function(){

Comment: Dont think so. $('#type1 #type22') will translate as id type22 followed by id type1.
If you want two different id to do same mouseover function, you will need that function to be external function to call from. Something like:
  $("#type1").mouseover(function(){highlight()});
  $("#type22").mouseover(function(){highlight()});
 function highlight() {
      $("#type1").css("background-color", "red");
      $("#type22").css("background-color", "red");
 }

See updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MqUyx/

Comment: Oh ok, i was trying to take a shortcut. seems not so lucky. Thanks for the help. Both of you!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr:eq(2) td[id^=type]').hover(function() {
    var id = this.id.replace(/type/, ''),
        targetId = id.concat(id);
    $('#type' + targetId).andSelf().css('background', 'red');
}, function() {
    var id = this.id.replace(/type/, ''),
        targetId = id.concat(id);
    $('#type' + targetId).andSelf().css('background', 'transparent');
})​;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2yMt2/3/)**